# Add per-site metas to the stackexchange.com sites list

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, stackexchange.com

The page https://stackexchange.com/sites currently only has stats on the main sites on the network. The metas are an important part of how Stack Exchange works

[image: MISSING!]

By adding them, it demonstrates that they're an important part of the eco-system and provides a few interesting facts for those of us that are interested.

Comment: I think the tab is a nice idea, but I'd propose that the Meta sites *only* show up in that tab, and not mixed in with all the other sites. I'm not really a fan of instantly doubling the list just to list those out.